# Translate curl request to axios request for AWS lambda function

Tags: node.js, curl, axios

I'm trying to translate a `curl` request to an `axios` request as such:

Here is the curl request format:

```
curl -s -X POST \
  -d '{"version": "12ac28616dba364cc9f1e30c610c6efd62dbe9b9c7d1d03ea", "input": {"prompt": "sunset over a lake in the mountains"}' \
  -H "Authorization: Token 123123123123123123" \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  https://api.replicate.com/v1/predictions
```

And here is how I translated it to an `axios` request:

```
try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      "https://api.replicate.com/v1/predictions",
      '{"version": "12ac28616dba364cc9f1e30c610c6efd62dbe9b9c7d1d03ea", "input": {"prompt": "sunset over a lake in the mountains"}',
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: "Token 123123123123123123",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }
    );

    console.log("RESPONSE ----->", response);
  } catch (err) {
    console.info("ERROR---->", err);
  }
```

However, I keep receiving the following error:

```
ERROR----> [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400] {
  code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST'
```

Is the code formatted properly?

Full error:

```
2022-07-04T15:14:47.902Z    d13a7d45-eb0b-4365-a721-f06f2f2fc968    INFO    ERROR----> [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400] {
  code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: { FormData: [Function] },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'Token 123123123',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.27.2',
      'Content-Length': 150
    },
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://api.replicate.com/v1/predictions',
    data: '"{\\"version\\": \\"2e3975b1692cd6aecac28616dba364cc9f1e30c610c6efd62dbe9b9c7d1d03ea\\", \\"input\\": {\\"prompt\\": \\"sunset over a lake in the mountains\\"}"'
  },
  request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
    _events: [Object: null prototype] {
      abort: [Function (anonymous)],
      aborted: [Function (anonymous)],
      connect: [Function (anonymous)],
      error: [Function (anonymous)],
      socket: [Function (anonymous)],
      timeout: [Function (anonymous)],
      prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish]
    },
    _eventsCount: 7,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    outputData: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    destroyed: false,
    _last: true,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: false,
    _defaultKeepAlive: true,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    _contentLength: null,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: true,
    _headerSent: true,
    socket: TLSSocket {
      _tlsOptions: [Object],
      _secureEstablished: true,
      _securePending: false,
      _newSessionPending: false,
      _controlReleased: true,
      secureConnecting: false,
      _SNICallback: null,
      servername: 'api.replicate.com',
      alpnProtocol: false,
      authorized: true,
      authorizationError: null,
      encrypted: true,
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 10,
      connecting: false,
      _hadError: false,
      _parent: null,
      _host: 'api.replicate.com',
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: false,
      _sockname: null,
      _pendingData: null,
      _pendingEncoding: '',
      server: undefined,
      _server: null,
      ssl: [TLSWrap],
      _requestCert: true,
      _rejectUnauthorized: true,
      parser: null,
      _httpMessage: [Circular *1],
      [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(verified)]: true,
      [Symbol(pendingSession)]: null,
      [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 6,
      [Symbol(kHandle)]: [TLSWrap],
      [Symbol(kSetNoDelay)]: false,
      [Symbol(lastWriteQueueSize)]: 0,
      [Symbol(timeout)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBuffer)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferCb)]: null,
      [Symbol(kBufferGen)]: null,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kBytesRead)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kBytesWritten)]: 0,
      [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object],
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    _header: 'POST /v1/predictions HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
      'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
      'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
      'Authorization: Token 123123123123123\r\n' +
      'User-Agent: axios/0.27.2\r\n' +
      'Content-Length: 150\r\n' +
      'Host: api.replicate.com\r\n' +
      'Connection: close\r\n' +
      '\r\n',
    _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
    _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
    agent: Agent {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 2,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      defaultPort: 443,
      protocol: 'https:',
      options: [Object],
      requests: {},
      sockets: [Object],
      freeSockets: {},
      keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
      keepAlive: false,
      maxSockets: Infinity,
      maxFreeSockets: 256,
      scheduling: 'lifo',
      maxTotalSockets: Infinity,
      totalSocketCount: 1,
      maxCachedSessions: 100,
      _sessionCache: [Object],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    socketPath: undefined,
    method: 'POST',
    maxHeaderSize: undefined,
    insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
    path: '/v1/predictions',
    _ended: true,
    res: IncomingMessage {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 4,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      httpVersionMajor: 1,
      httpVersionMinor: 1,
      httpVersion: '1.1',
      complete: true,
      headers: [Object],
      rawHeaders: [Array],
      trailers: {},
      rawTrailers: [],
      aborted: false,
      upgrade: false,
      url: '',
      method: null,
      statusCode: 400,
      statusMessage: 'Bad Request',
      client: [TLSSocket],
      _consuming: false,
      _dumped: false,
      req: [Circular *1],
      responseUrl: 'https://api.replicate.com/v1/predictions',
      redirects: [],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(RequestTimeout)]: undefined
    },
    aborted: false,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    reusedSocket: false,
    host: 'api.replicate.com',
    protocol: 'https:',
    _redirectable: Writable {
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 3,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _options: [Object],
      _ended: true,
      _ending: true,
      _redirectCount: 0,
      _redirects: [],
      _requestBodyLength: 150,
      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
      _onNativeResponse: [Function (anonymous)],
      _currentRequest: [Circular *1],
      _currentUrl: 'https://api.replicate.com/v1/predictions',
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    },
    [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
    [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
    [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
    [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype] {
      accept: [Array],
      'content-type': [Array],
      authorization: [Array],
      'user-agent': [Array],
      'content-length': [Array],
      host: [Array]
    }
  },
  response: {
    status: 400,
    statusText: 'Bad Request',
    headers: {
      date: 'Mon, 04 Jul 2022 15:14:47 GMT',
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'content-length': '74',
      connection: 'close',
      allow: 'GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS',
      'x-frame-options': 'DENY',
      'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
      'referrer-policy': 'same-origin',
      'cross-origin-opener-policy': 'same-origin',
      via: '1.1 vegur',
      'cf-cache-status': 'DYNAMIC',
      'expect-ct': 'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"',
      'report-to': '{"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\\/\\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\\/report\\/v3?s=BBZ%2FuLKvNnSPD5CiPhRgFwAJA2cjjQUj29MokMhPaNhdRqCr%2Fe4xMan2uLUk2YW3q10spY8wQPnRlmhFUfg6N5t4kLVwBqmKs2UD%2B8Q9Fx7v5zXNpoV%2FkTNRt352MjWtAmKV"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}',
      nel: '{"success_fraction":0,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}',
      'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=15552000',
      server: 'cloudflare',
      'cf-ray': '7258d008fc19823f-IAD'
    },
    config: {
      transitional: [Object],
      adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
      transformRequest: [Array],
      transformResponse: [Array],
      timeout: 0,
      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
      maxContentLength: -1,
      maxBodyLength: -1,
      env: [Object],
      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
      headers: [Object],
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://api.replicate.com/v1/predictions',
      data: '"{\\"version\\": \\"2e3975b1692cd6aecac28616dba364cc9f1e30c610c6efd62dbe9b9c7d1d03ea\\", \\"input\\": {\\"prompt\\": \\"sunset over a lake in the mountains\\"}"'
    },
    request: <ref *1> ClientRequest {
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 7,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      outputData: [],
      outputSize: 0,
      writable: true,
      destroyed: false,
      _last: true,
      chunkedEncoding: false,
      shouldKeepAlive: false,
      _defaultKeepAlive: true,
      useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
      sendDate: false,
      _removedConnection: false,
      _removedContLen: false,
      _removedTE: false,
      _contentLength: null,
      _hasBody: true,
      _trailer: '',
      finished: true,
      _headerSent: true,
      socket: [TLSSocket],
      _header: 'POST /v1/predictions HTTP/1.1\r\n' +
        'Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n' +
        'Content-Type: application/json\r\n' +
        'Authorization: Token 123123123123123\r\n' +
        'User-Agent: axios/0.27.2\r\n' +
        'Content-Length: 150\r\n' +
        'Host: api.replicate.com\r\n' +
        'Connection: close\r\n' +
        '\r\n',
      _keepAliveTimeout: 0,
      _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
      agent: [Agent],
      socketPath: undefined,
      method: 'POST',
      maxHeaderSize: undefined,
      insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
      path: '/v1/predictions',
      _ended: true,
      res: [IncomingMessage],
      aborted: false,
      timeoutCb: null,
      upgradeOrConnect: false,
      parser: null,
      maxHeadersCount: null,
      reusedSocket: false,
      host: 'api.replicate.com',
      protocol: 'https:',
      _redirectable: [Writable],
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kNeedDrain)]: false,
      [Symbol(corked)]: 0,
      [Symbol(kOutHeaders)]: [Object: null prototype]
    },
    data: { non_field_errors: [Array] }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting the `Token` part in the `Authorization` header:

```
Authorization: "123123123123123123"
```

If you look on the response from your axios call you will see this:

```
data: { detail: 'Authentication credentials were not provided.' }
```

So just update your code and add the `Token`:

```
Authorization: "Token 123123123123123123"
```

I also think you might have problem with you actual data, try sending it like this instead:

```
const response = await axios.post(
  "https://api.replicate.com/v1/predictions",
  {
    version: "12ac28616dba364cc9f1e30c610c6efd62dbe9b9c7d1d03ea",
    input: {
      prompt: "sunset over a lake in the mountains"
    }
  },
  {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Token 123123123123123123",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  }
);
```

or serialize the data before you send it:

```
const data = JSON.stringify({
    version: "12ac28616dba364cc9f1e30c610c6efd62dbe9b9c7d1d03ea",
    input: {
      prompt: "sunset over a lake in the mountains"
    }
});
const response = await axios.post(
  "https://api.replicate.com/v1/predictions", data,
  {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Token 123123123123123123",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  }
);
```

As you can see in your error message the data is getting escaped, so this is probably the problem:

```
data: '"{\\"version\\": \\"2e3975b1692cd6aecac28616dba364cc9f1e30c610c6efd62dbe9b9c7d1d03ea\\", \\"input\\": {\\"prompt\\": \\"sunset over a lake in the mountains\\"}"'
```

Comment: Weird, still getting same error

Comment: Very strange, if I add the `Token` part I get this instead: `data: { detail: 'Invalid token.' }`, which seems correct since you hopefully not added a valid token in your question.

Comment: Can you try to get a more descriptive error message?

Comment: Just added the full error

Comment: This `data: { non_field_errors: [Array] }` seems to tell you that there is something wrong with the data, but the first time you got the error it was because of the missing `Token` part. This is something else. Not sure what `non_field_errors` mean, perhaps you could check the documentation?

Comment: Hmmm, still can't figure it out

Comment: Did you try sending the data as I suggested above?